# how to create nested list using flat JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, grouping

JSON

```
[
{"CountryID":1,"CountryName":"Austria","CountryG2":"Austria","CountryG3":"DACH","CountryG4":"Western Europe"},
{"CountryID":2,"CountryName":"Germany","CountryG2":"Germany","CountryG3":"DACH","CountryG4":"Western Europe"},
{"CountryID":3,"CountryName":"Ireland, United Kingdom","CountryG2":"UK&I","CountryG3":"UK&I","CountryG4":"Western Europe"},
{"CountryID":4,"CountryName":"Belarus","CountryG2":"Belarus","CountryG3":"ESE","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":5,"CountryName":"Bosnia","CountryG2":"Bosnia","CountryG3":"ESE","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":6,"CountryName":"Serbia","CountryG2":"Serbia","CountryG3":"ESE","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":7,"CountryName":"Croatia","CountryG2":"Croatia","CountryG3":"ESE","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":8,"CountryName":"Greece","CountryG2":"Greece","CountryG3":"ESE","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":9,"CountryName":"Poland","CountryG2":"Poland","CountryG3":"Central Europe","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":10,"CountryName":"Czech Republic","CountryG2":"Czech Republic","CountryG3":"Central Europe","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":12,"CountryName":"Slovakia","CountryG2":"Slovakia","CountryG3":"Central Europe","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":13,"CountryName":"Hungary","CountryG2":"Hungary","CountryG3":"Central Europe","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":14,"CountryName":"Israel","CountryG2":"Israel","CountryG3":"Central Europe","CountryG4":"CEMA"},
{"CountryID":15,"CountryName":"Russia","CountryG2":"Russia","CountryG3":"Russia","CountryG4":"CEMA"}
]
```

**Group by** 
CountryG4 > CountryG3 > CountryG2 > CountryName

Comment: Put your JSON in a code snippet

Comment: And show us what you have tried. SO is not a code ordering service where you just drop your requirements.

Comment: so, you need some js, php, jquery(js) ... or is this a survey of some kind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested hash table approach.

```js
var data = [{ CountryID: 1, CountryName: "Austria", CountryG2: "Austria", CountryG3: "DACH", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 2, CountryName: "Germany", CountryG2: "Germany", CountryG3: "DACH", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 3, CountryName: "Ireland, United Kingdom", CountryG2: "UK&I", CountryG3: "UK&I", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 4, CountryName: "Belarus", CountryG2: "Belarus", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 5, CountryName: "Bosnia", CountryG2: "Bosnia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 6, CountryName: "Serbia", CountryG2: "Serbia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 7, CountryName: "Croatia", CountryG2: "Croatia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 8, CountryName: "Greece", CountryG2: "Greece", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 9, CountryName: "Poland", CountryG2: "Poland", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 10, CountryName: "Czech Republic", CountryG2: "Czech Republic", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 12, CountryName: "Slovakia", CountryG2: "Slovakia", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 13, CountryName: "Hungary", CountryG2: "Hungary", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 14, CountryName: "Israel", CountryG2: "Israel", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 15, CountryName: "Russia", CountryG2: "Russia", CountryG3: "Russia", CountryG4: "CEMA" }],
    keys = ['CountryG4', 'CountryG3', 'CountryG2'],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (!r[a[k]]) {
            r[a[k]] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ name: a[k], children: r[a[k]]._ });
        }
        return r[a[k]];
    }, this)._.push({ CountryID: a.CountryID, CountryName: a.CountryName });
}, { _: result });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same but without using `thisArg` of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var data = [{ CountryID: 1, CountryName: "Austria", CountryG2: "Austria", CountryG3: "DACH", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 2, CountryName: "Germany", CountryG2: "Germany", CountryG3: "DACH", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 3, CountryName: "Ireland, United Kingdom", CountryG2: "UK&I", CountryG3: "UK&I", CountryG4: "Western Europe" }, { CountryID: 4, CountryName: "Belarus", CountryG2: "Belarus", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 5, CountryName: "Bosnia", CountryG2: "Bosnia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 6, CountryName: "Serbia", CountryG2: "Serbia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 7, CountryName: "Croatia", CountryG2: "Croatia", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 8, CountryName: "Greece", CountryG2: "Greece", CountryG3: "ESE", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 9, CountryName: "Poland", CountryG2: "Poland", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 10, CountryName: "Czech Republic", CountryG2: "Czech Republic", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 12, CountryName: "Slovakia", CountryG2: "Slovakia", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 13, CountryName: "Hungary", CountryG2: "Hungary", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 14, CountryName: "Israel", CountryG2: "Israel", CountryG3: "Central Europe", CountryG4: "CEMA" }, { CountryID: 15, CountryName: "Russia", CountryG2: "Russia", CountryG3: "Russia", CountryG4: "CEMA" }],
    keys = ['CountryG4', 'CountryG3', 'CountryG2'],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (a) {
        keys.reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (!r[a[k]]) {
                r[a[k]] = { _: [] };
                r._.push({ name: a[k], children: r[a[k]]._ });
            }
            return r[a[k]];
        }, hash)._.push({ CountryID: a.CountryID, CountryName: a.CountryName });
    };
}({ _: result }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: crazy! can you let me know if I understood this correctly: 1) iterate values 2) reduce on keys array. 3) set execution context of ForEach to object key "_" value "result" empty array.  4). push into the empty array inside of forEach utilizing it's "this". 5) push into "result" an object containing the country name along with their parent countryId. 5) Then you check to see if there is an array who's country name is hashed by your array of keys 6) If there is no array literal with that hashed name you assign it an object key property empty array value, where you push name children properties?

Comment: this function can be used for creating list ?

Comment: @arrow, right, you understand it correctly. if you like, you could replace `this`with a closure over the dame value.

Comment: @Kiranm, right, it helps to create with the keys a nested structure, which follows the sam building pattern for every level. the last level could contain a custom structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse() function for this.
Assuming you have this json in a variable, data.
You can do something like

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

This will give you nice a nice javascript object with all the required nesting.

If you have this JSON saved in a file on node.js you can do something like

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("filename.json"));
```

Comment: OP did not specify whether a js or php solution is asked.  Dont answer bad questions like this.

Comment: I assumed it was javascript from the tags. A complete novice with stackoverflow here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next one (if it's PHP related):

```
$data = [
    ["CountryID" => 1, ... // put your array here
];
// or use: $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$store = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $store[$val['CountryG4']][$val['CountryG3']][$val['CountryG2']] = $val['CountryName'];
}

var_dump($store);
```

If it's a JavaScript issue:

```
var store = {};
json.forEach(function (data) {
    store[data.CountryG4][data.CountryG3][data.CountryG2] = data.CountryName;
});

console.log(store);
```